# Dismiss Multiple ModalViewControllers in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, modalviewcontroller

**iPhone ModalViewController**: In iOS 4, it is possible to dismiss multiple ModalViewControllers using:

```
[[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] parentViewController]
       dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In iOS 5, the code is not working.

How do I dismiss multiple modalViewControllers in iOS 5?

Answer (score 6):

yeah, this is an annoying change. for modal view controllers, you now have to call `presentingViewController` instead of `parentViewController`

Answer (score 0):

Hi In iOS 5 Use the below Code

```
[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```